# Regex for decimal number and blank Swift

Tags: regex, swift

I want a regex in swift matches all decimal numbers and integers, the requirement is following:

```
Reject these non-numbers:
. (single decimal point)
2.2.2 (two or more decimal points in any order)
-. (negative decimal point)
+. (plus decimal point)
(empty string)
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a regex, why not just try converting the String to a Float. You can put the following in a Swift playground to see that it works:

```
func isNumber(s: String) -> Bool {
    return Float(s) != nil
}

// Your criteria
isNumber(".")     // false
isNumber("2.2.2") // false
isNumber("-.")    // false
isNumber("+.")    // false
isNumber("")      // false

// Validity check
isNumber("2.2") // true
isNumber("2")   // true
isNumber("-2")  // true
```

Comment: Thank you for simplifying my solution.

Answer (score 0):

If validating user input, rather a regex, why not just try converting the `String` to a number user `NSNumberFormatter`. This gets you out of writing regex and handles international formats, too (e.g. in Germany, they enter `2.3` as `2,3`):

```
let numberFormatter: NSNumberFormatter = {
    let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .DecimalStyle
    return formatter
}()

func isNumber(s: String) -> Bool {
    return numberFormatter.numberFromString(s) != nil
}
```